# confusion on unique key vs PK

Tags: mysql, etl, teradata-sql-assistant

hi guys I have a one question. I searched and google for ok abs unique key concepts. But got some confusion. There can be only one PK in a table but can have multiple unique index right. So, does this mean one one column in a table will be the PK and for unique index there can be multiple columns. Could you please make me clear on this?

Answer (score 1):

Neither PK nor the unique index have to be single-column. They can both span multiple columns.

Comment: @Godon Bobic So, what is the difference then between PK and unique key if both can have multiple columns, besides the fact the Unique key can have null values while Pk cannot.

Comment: Conceptually, there is no difference. There may be differences in the implementation specific to each database. For example, in InnoDB, all secondary indexes, unique or otherwise, point to PK, and an InnoDB table is always clustered on it's PK.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can have also have a multiple column [primary key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html), which means that the combination of all columns has to be unique and Indexed

A unique Constraint only guarantees that every row in that column is unique.

A [KEY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html) is a indexed column which can be *[UNIQUE | FULLTEXT | SPATIAL]*